# Elasticsearch query returning far less number of records

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running following elasticsearch query from groovy script. There are thousands of records which meet this criteria, but I get only 10 records in return.

```
{ 
"query":{ 
  "bool":{ 
     "must":[ 
        { 
           "match_all":{ 

           }
        },
        { 
           "range":{ 
              "@Timestamp":{ 
                 "gte":1417511269270,
                 "lte":1575277669270,
                 "format":"epoch_millis"
              }
           }
        },
        { 
           "match_phrase":{ 
              "field1.keyword":{ 
                 "query":"value1"
              }
           }
        },
        { 
           "match_phrase":{ 
              "field2.keyword":{ 
                 "query":"value2"
              }
           }
        },
        { 
           "range":{ 
              "@Timestamp":{ 
                 "gte":"2001-03-01",
                 "lt":"2019-10-30"
              }
           }
        }
     ],
     "filter":[ 

     ],
     "should":[ 

     ],
     "must_not":[ 

     ]
  }
 }
}
```

What am I missing in my query?

Comment: Why do you have two different constraints on the same field `@Timestamp` ?

Comment: You might want to look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a [size parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size), which means it defaults to 10 results.

e.g. add this to your query object:

```
"size": 100
```